# Shared UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, userdefaults

I want to share data between iPhone and Apple Watch with shared UserDefaults (with AppGroup), but the communication between these two doesn't work. When I look at actual stored files in the shared Container, I found out that they do not use the same container. Can someone help me with this?

Code on watch:

```
let suiteName = "group.suitname"
if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: suiteName) {
   userDefaults.set(inputText, forKey: "watchTransfer")
   let groupPath = FileManager().containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: suiteName)!.appendingPathComponent("Library/Preferences")
   print(groupPath)
   print(userDefaults.string(forKey: "watchTransfer") ?? "Nothing stored")
}
```

Code on iPhone:

```
let suiteName = "group.suitname"
if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: suiteName) {
   let string = userDefaults.string(forKey: "watchTransfer") ?? "Nothing stored"
   print("Fetched: \(string)")
   let groupPath = FileManager().containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: suiteName)!.appendingPathComponent("Library/Preferences")
   print(groupPath)
   return string
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with "modern" WatchOS.

Reference:

[Apple developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/89859)

You would need to use another transfer mechanism. Like [Watchconnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity).